# System output not displaying in web browser php

Tags: php, system, exec, output

I have a command I have tested in the terminal and it works fine, but when I call the command in my script to display the output on the browser it doesn't seem to work. My command takes time for it to display the output in the terminal would this be a contribution why its not displaying on the browser.

```
set_time_limit (0); 
echo '<pre>';
$output=array();
$last_line = system('cat /home/me/dev/test/working/test_string.txt | java -jar /home/simon/logstash/build/logstash-1.1.10.dev-monolithic.jar agent -f /home/me/dev/test/working/my_itch_con.config',$output);
echo '</pre>';
echo "Complete";
print_r($output);
echo "<br>";
```

Comment: It displays the log results just want it to appear on the browser. when the process is been executed it does take a minute to display the output.

Comment: That I understand. But now what it displays in browser ?

Comment: from php.net , when you give second argument to `system` function ,then the return status of the executed command will be written to this variable.

Comment: Try the example in my answer. Make sure you have done it rite way.

Answer (score 2):

Parameters to the `system` (It will not show you the output, it just return you the status of the command)

**command**

The command that will be executed.

**return_var**

If the return_var argument is present, 
        then the return status of the executed command will 
        be written to this variable.

////////////////////////////////**......................................................................................**///////////////////////////////////////////

```
Use `exec` command instead
```

**command**

The command that will be executed.

**output**

If the output argument is present, then the specified array will be filled with every line of output from the command. Trailing whitespace, such as \n, is not included in this array. Note that if the array already contains some elements, exec() will append to the end of the array. If you do not want the function to append elements, call unset() on the array before passing it to exec().

**return_var**

If the return_var argument is present along with the output argument, then the return status of the executed command will be written to this variable.

**EG:-**

```
exec('whoami', $test, $arr);

print_r($test);
```

In browser it o/p

```
Array ( [0] => nt authority\system )
```

For more info

http://php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php

Answer (score 0):

Confirm whether you disable `system` function in php.ini in `disable_function` block

When set error_reporting(E_ALL) to display all error

Comment: @Sahal Yes I know, so I think it's PHP configuration problem

Comment: @likai why would i have disabled the system function whenever I use the system function and it works in the terminal?

Comment: There is no system function that make works in terminal and not in browser. The answer you have given is no where near to his question

Comment: @Sahal If `system` function disabled, call it will return an waring. so set error_reporting(E_ALL) can catch it. correct me if I'm wrong

Comment: @Sahal what would you suggest?

Comment: Try with `exec` function instead of `system`

Comment: @Meryvn nothing to return?

Comment: @Meryvn Maybe is permission denied

Comment: It couldn't be because I have executed ruby files with system function and also it has displayed on my browser.

Comment: Oh, you can try modify command for `ls` see it is work? if working should be permission denied, otherwise I don't how to do.

Comment: ls command works. how can give permissions, do i need to give permissions to www-data

Comment: Oh good, PHP running on apache user, as long as you give apache user to related command/files execute/access permission it is ok, I think is that. I think so.

Comment: Am trying to give www-data permissions am struggling

Comment: i have given www-data admin rights edited the passwd and group files